# Help with forming a dimensionless combination proportional to $e^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

I am currently working on a physics problem that asks me to form a dimensionless combination of the fundamental constants $e=\left|q_e\right|$, $\hbar$, $c$, and $\epsilon_0$ that is proportional to $e^2$. This dimensionless number is called the fine structure constant.

I have been struggling with this problem and would greatly appreciate any help or guidance.

Here is my attempt at solving the problem so far:

I know that the finestructure constant $\alpha$ is given by:
$$
\alpha=\frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 \hbar c}
$$

So, I need to somehow form a combination of $e$, $\hbar$, $c$, and $\epsilon_0$ that is proportional to $e^2$. I also know that $\epsilon_0$ has units of $\text{F}/\text{m}$, which are equivalent to $\text{C}^2/(\text{J} \cdot \text{m})$.

My attempt was to start with:

$$\alpha \propto \frac{e^2}{\epsilon_0 \hbar c}$$

And then try to form a dimensionless combination by dividing the numerator and denominator by appropriate powers of $e$, $\hbar$, $c$, and $\epsilon_0$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Right answer should be:
$$\frac{e^2}{\epsilon_0 \hbar c}$$

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm very confused by this question. You have your dimensionless constant: It's the fine structure constant, and it's already proportional to $e^2$. Can you clarify? The factors of $4\pi$ are irrelevant.  You can either put them in there (which is done by convention), or you leave them out.  There's no derivation there; it's just a choice.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly evaluating the dimensions of $e^2/\epsilon_0 \hbar c$? What do you get when you try it?

Comment: $$\frac{e^{2}}{\epsilon_{0} \hbar c} =\frac{\left[ C\right]^{2}  }{\left[ \frac{\left[ C\right]^{2}  }{\left[ N\right]  \left[ m\right]^{2}  } \right]  \left[ \left[ kg\right]  \left[ \frac{m}{s^{2}} \right]  \right]  \left[ \frac{m}{s} \right]  }$$ 
$$=\frac{\left[ C\right]^{2}  }{\left[ \frac{\left[ C\right]^{2}  }{\left[ \left[ kg\right]  \left[ \frac{m}{s^{2}} \right]  \right]  \left[ m\right]^{2}  } \right]  \left[ \left[ kg\right]  \left[ \frac{m}{s^{2}} \right]  \right]  \left[ \frac{m}{s} \right]  }$$

Comment: $$=\frac{\left[ C\right]^{2}  }{\left[ \frac{\left[ C\right]^{2}  }{\left[ \frac{kgm^{3}}{s^{2}} \right]  } \right]  \left[ \frac{kgm^{2}}{s^{3}} \right]  }$$

Comment: You've used units of $\hbar$ that are $[kg][m/s^2]$. It should be $[J][s]=[kg][m^2/s^2][s]=[kg][m^2/s]$. Also be sure to simplify the expression as far as you can.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

Base SI units of $e^2$ are $C^2$. So you need to divide by a collection of the other constants with units $C^2$ so they cancel out $\epsilon_0$ has units of $C^2/Nm^2$ (from Coulomb's Law). That's a good sign, we see $C^2$, so then we just need to multiply that by something with units of $Nm^2$ so that cancels out $N = kgm/s^2$, so $Nm^2 = kgm^3/s^2$ $\hbar$ has units of $kgm^2/s$ (angular momentum) $c$ has units of $m/s$ (speed) if we multiply those together, we get $kgm^3/s^2$, which is exactly what we wanted to cancel out. So dividing $e^2$ by $\epsilon_0 \hbar c$ gives us a dimensionless collection of constants.

Answer (score 0):

This answer provides a derivation of the proportionality constant, $\alpha$, which relates the electric potential energy of two charges and the energy of a particle with a de Broglie wavelength. It uses equations for photon energy and electric potential energy, and then uses the de Broglie wavelength to relate the two energy quantities. The proportionality constant is found by setting the two energy quantities equal and solving for $\alpha$. The final equation for $\alpha$ involves fundamental constants such as the electron charge, Planck's constant, the speed of light, and the vacuum permittivity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oh gosh, the answer key's argument that you posted, is so horrible. Instead, a much easier way is via the following. The unit of energy is joules:
$$
[E  ] = \left [ \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r} \right ] = J \qquad \implies \qquad [E r] = \left [ \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0  } \right ] = J m
$$
Next, consider the classical expression of action, coming from Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics. Things like $px - Et$ shows that momentum times distance has the same units as energy times time, and is also the same as action, also the same as angular momentum times unitless angle. These things are all proportional to Planck's constant, or else you cannot get a unitless thing to apply mathematical functions like exponential function on them. That is,
$$
[E t] = [\hslash] = J s \qquad \implies \qquad \left [ \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 \hslash} \right ] = m/s = [c]
$$
And then the result is obvious.

Comment: Could you dumb this down for me please? I'm still doing HS Physics.

Comment: Do you understand that $e^2/\epsilon_0$ has units of joules metres, and hbar has units of Joules seconds, so the division of them gives you speed units?

Comment: I know that e has the SI-unit Coulomb, which is 1J/1V. Not sure about the espilon or the hbar though.

Comment: Im using coulomb potential to convert $e^2/\epsilon_0$ together. You need to know some quantum theory to know hbar's units.